# PySpark DataFrame - force eager dataframe cache - take(1) vs count()

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

One of the approaches to force caching/persistence is calling an action after cache/persistent, for example:

```
df.cache().count()
```

As mentioned here: [in spark streaming must i call count() after cache() or persist() to force caching/persistence to really happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43728505)

**Question:**

Is there any difference if `take(1)` is called instead of `count()`? Will entire dataframe be cached into memory and/or disk when `take(1)` is used?

I noticed that `df.cache().take(1)` is faster but my intention is only to achieve eager caching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `take(1)`, then it will evaluate only part of the dataframe, not the whole one - that's why `count` is more often used, although any other action that evaluates the whole dataframe could be used.

This case is specifically mentioned in the 2nd edition of Learning Spark book that is [freely available from Databrick's site](https://databricks.com/p/ebook/learning-spark-from-oreilly).

Comment: nobody knows, but from performance point of view is makes sense - why we need to calculate everything if we asked only for one record

Comment: No I get that, but more about the count, sorry.

Comment: it's really interesting question - connectors may even do the predicates pushdown for count operation, so no pulling of the data happens (for example, Spark Cassandra Connector could do it when used on cluster with DSE Search enabled)

Comment: indeed...columnar aspects of DF, DS, why would you need to get all